# How can I determine the max and the min and the average of some numbers?

Tags: c++

The program objective:

> Write a program which allows a teacher to determine the min, max, and average grade from grades entered. The teacher will continuously enter grades until the sentinel is specified. For this example, a grade of -1 will be used to denote grading is completed. The min, max, and average grade should then be displayed to the teacher. This program should not accept invalid grades to be used [0, 100].

I have attached a picture of my code, please have a look. When I run it, it shows me that there is an error.

[image]

Comment: You should search the internet and StackOverflow before posting.  I have answered a lot of these.

Comment: Please post your code as text.  Images don't paste very well into IDEs.  Also, images don't scale well either.  Links may be blocked by firewalls.

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.  We can't easily copy-paste images to run your code, and images don't show up in searches if someone has the same issue in the future.

Comment: You want to compute an average of a userè-deined number of scores, yet you do not count the number of scores entered, nor a sum of the scores...   Your evaluation of tha max score is wrong , since max is always the last valid entry...   Your evaluation of min is always 0.  min and max are not initialized right...  max should be iinitialized with 0, and min with 100 for correct min and max evauations....  You should write down the mathematical equations before writing the first line of code, that always helps a lot.

Comment: Try this exercise:  highlight the lines in your IDE.  Copy to the clipboard (usually Ctrl+C).  Edit your post.  Paste from clipboard into your post.  Format as necessary.

Comment: Your `count` and `stop` variables are not used. Your `average` calculation will be incorrect if the User enters 4 or less or more than 5 values.  Your sum and average will be incorrect if the User enters a value greater than 100 or less than -1.

Comment: Definitely, use a debugger and step through your code, watching the values of the variables.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start at the bottom and work our way up.
**Reading numbers**

```
int number = 0;
while (std::cin >> number)
{
    if (number == -1) break;
}
```

**Running Sum**
The sum is the addition of every number; no need to store numbers in a container.

```
int number = 0;
int sum = 0;
while (std::cin >> number)
{
    if (number == -1) break;
    sum += number;
}
```

**Running Maximum**
This one is a little bit tricky.  The maximum wants to be the first value entered.

```
int number = 0;
int sum = 0;
int maximum = 0; // All variables should be initialized.
std::cin >> maximum;
sum = maximum;
if (maximum == -1)
{
    return 0;
}
while (std::cin >> number)
{
    if (number == -1) break;
    sum += number;
    if (number > maximum)
    {
        maximum = number;
    }
}
```

The calculation of the minimum and average is left as an exercise for the OP (You need to do *some* work on your own).

Hint:  Average is the `sum` divided by the quantity of numbers entered.  Be aware that the average needs at least 1 value so that there is no division by zero (usually 3 values are used for an average).  Again, no container necessary for this either.

*I posted this answer without looking at the OP's code since the OP originally posted a link to an image and firewalls are blocking the link.*

Comment: I've read the code, and you surmized right,  Realistically, without trying to be mean, OP was shooting for a solid F.

Comment: Your "Running Maximum" code can be simplified to remove the I/O before the `while` loop: `int number = 0, sum = 0, maximum = -1; while (std::cin >> number) { if (number == -1) break; sum += number; if (number > maximum) { maximum = number; } }`